# Form submitting multiple times when created dynamically using AJAX/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, google-app-engine

I'm using Google Maps API in a project, and the infoWindow content is built dynamically, so i cant use document ready function to assign the validator to the form.

I'm using, bootstrap, bootstrapValidator and jQuery.

I created a function, and the submit button call it, in the first click, ok, 1 call, second click, 2 calls, 3calls, 4 calls, etc...

**What i need to do, to the Submit only be called only once?**

**THIS ONLY HAPPENS WITH THE DYNAMICALLY CONTENT, the static forms have a normal behavior.**

Here's the code, take a look please.

Here's the content that creates on fly:

```
var content_string = '<div class="scrollFix"> <div id="divinfowindow"> <div class="container-fluid container-fluid-corrige"></div> <div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-3 img-corrige-60"> <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" class="img-rounded"/> </div> <div class="col-sm-9 text-corrige"> <p>Por: Russell Bega</p> <p>Em: </p> <p class="white-space-normal">endereco</p> </div> </div> <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="formNovaMarcacao" action="/novaMarcacao"> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-sm-12"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTituloNovaMarc" name="inputTituloNovaMarc" placeholder="Titulo"> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-sm-12"> <select id="inputCategoriaNovaMarc" name="inputCategoriaNovaMarc" class="form-control select-corrige"> <option>Escolha uma categoria</option> </select> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-sm-12"> <select id="inputSubCategoriaNovaMarc" name="inputSubCategoriaNovaMarc"class="form-control select-corrige"> <option>Escolha uma categoria</option> </select> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-sm-12"> <textarea class="form-control" id="inputDescricaoNovaMarc" name="inputDescricaoNovaMarc" rows="3" placeholder="Descricao"></textarea> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="pull-right"> <button type="submit" id="btnNovaMarc" onclick="validaNovaMarcacao()" name="btnNovaMarc" class="btn btn-default" data-loading-text="Postando...">Postar</button> </div> </div> </form> <div id="statusNovaMarc"></div> </div> </div>';
```

And here's the validator code:

```
function validaNovaMarcacao(){
    $('#formNovaMarcacao').bootstrapValidator({ 
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        container: 'tooltip',
        submitButtons: btnNovaMarc,
        fields: {
            inputTituloNovaMarc: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Este campo não pode ser vazio.'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
.on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();

                var dados = {
                    inputTituloNovaMarc : $("#inputTituloNovaMarc").val(),
                };

                var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

                //console.log(dados);
                $('#btnNovaMarc').button('loading');

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: formURL,
                    data: dados,
                    success: function( data )
                    {
                        alert("ok" + data);

                    },
                    error : function (data){
                    }
                });

                $('#btnNovaMarc').button('reset');
            return false;
            });
}
```

Here's the content string indented:

```
<div class="scrollFix">
    <div id="divinfowindow">
        <div class="container-fluid container-fluid-corrige"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 img-corrige-60"> <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" class="img-rounded"/> </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 text-corrige">
                <p>Por: Russell Bega</p>
                <p>Em: </p>
                <p class="white-space-normal">endereco</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="formNovaMarcacao" action="/novaMarcacao">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTituloNovaMarc" name="inputTituloNovaMarc" placeholder="Titulo"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <select id="inputCategoriaNovaMarc" name="inputCategoriaNovaMarc" class="form-control select-corrige">
                        <option>Escolha uma categoria</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <select id="inputSubCategoriaNovaMarc" name="inputSubCategoriaNovaMarc"class="form-control select-corrige">
                        <option>Escolha uma categoria</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12"> <textarea class="form-control" id="inputDescricaoNovaMarc" name="inputDescricaoNovaMarc" rows="3" placeholder="Descricao"></textarea> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="pull-right"> <button type="submit" id="btnNovaMarc" onclick="validaNovaMarcacao()" name="btnNovaMarc" class="btn btn-default" data-loading-text="Postando...">Postar</button> </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="statusNovaMarc"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here the server side log, pay attention on timestamps.

```
INFO     2014-10-16 02:20:08,765 module.py:659] default: "POST /novaMarcacao HTTP/1.1" 200 -

INFO     2014-10-16 02:20:17,447 module.py:659] default: "POST /novaMarcacao HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2014-10-16 02:20:17,448 module.py:659] default: "POST /novaMarcacao HTTP/1.1" 200 -

INFO     2014-10-16 02:20:26,375 module.py:659] default: "POST /novaMarcacao HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2014-10-16 02:20:26,391 module.py:659] default: "POST /novaMarcacao HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2014-10-16 02:20:26,394 module.py:659] default: "POST /novaMarcacao HTTP/1.1" 200 -

INFO     2014-10-16 02:20:34,132 module.py:659] default: "POST /novaMarcacao HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2014-10-16 02:20:34,170 module.py:659] default: "POST /novaMarcacao HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2014-10-16 02:20:34,177 module.py:659] default: "POST /novaMarcacao HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2014-10-16 02:20:34,178 module.py:659] default: "POST /novaMarcacao HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: You might get more answers if you made sure there was a clear question in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following part from within the function `validaNovaMarcacao` and put it in DOM ready where it will be call only once:

```
$('#formNovaMarcacao').bootstrapValidator({
    //.....
.on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
    //......
});
```

As it is, each time you call the function `validaNovaMarcacao`, you are re-initializing the validator and attaching another success event handler; that's quite evident by the sequence of the number of calls: 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

Should be:

```
$(function() {
    $('#formNovaMarcacao').bootstrapValidator({
        //.....
    .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
        //......
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Following the discussion below, the following are the changes you need to make:

Reduce the function to the following:

```
function formNovaMarcacao() {
    $('#formNovaMarcacao').bootstrapValidator({
        //.....
    });
}
```

Then the following:

```
$(function() {
    formNovaMarcacao();
    $('#formNovaMarcacao').on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
        //......
    });
});
```

You would do well not to use inline JS `onclick=...` .. it's just not good practice. Run `formNovaMarcacao()` immediately the dynamic form content is created.

That should do it.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get what i need to do exactly. I tried to ` function validaNovaMarcacao(){
    $(function() {
    $('#formNovaMarcacao').bootstrapValidator({ //..... close close...`

Comment: You are calling the function `validaNovaMarcacao()` several times. Each time you call it, you're adding an extra form submission. Do away with the function or show the rest of your code.

Comment: Theres no more to show, i only have this, a form which is created on the fly when i click in the map, and the form calls the validaNovaMarcacao(), only the form call that function, but if i click the submit button more than one time, i get more and more calls.

Comment: For example, if the validation return error, i need to fix the fields and try to submit again, in this case i clicked 2 times on the submit button, (1 for validation, and get error, fixed the fiels, and other to try to submit again), i'll get 2 calls to the server.

Comment: When and where do you call that function?

Comment: <button type="submit" id="btnNovaMarc" onclick="validaNovaMarcacao()" name="btnNovaMarc" class="btn btn-default" data-loading-text="Postando...">Postar</button>

Comment: Only here, in the button from the form.

Comment: Ok, I see. Remove the `onclick=....` attribute. The `submit` button is sufficient to trigger the `submit` event. **That's what I was looking for.**

Comment: I cant, if i remove the onclick the function will not be called and the validator will not be used, the big problem here is, i cant use the validator on the ready document function, because the fields dont exist yet, then i need to use a function call. get it?

Comment: I didnt remove the `.on('success.form.bv', function(e) {      //......
});` because its do the ajax part, BUT i removed the onclick part and added the function call when the content_string is set! AND IT WORKED, THANK YOU!!!!